# Where do valence and conduction bands lie in periodic barrier structure?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, crystals

If we represent a periodic barrier structure as :
[image]
Where would valence bands and conduction bands lie wrt to these barrier structure?

Should not the conduction bands lie above barrier and valence bands below barrier height?

Comment: Aren’t conduction electrons bound in the system?

Comment: Yes, but can't we represent like barrier height is less than vaccum energy and then the conduction bands are above barrier but still less than vaccum energy ..?

Comment: So I can redefine the vacuum level to be anywhere I want? Why isn’t an electron with energy above V$_0$ unbound?

Comment: I honestly don't know , also normally where does vaccum energy lie wrt to valence and conduction bands?

Comment: Remember the photoelectric effect, the energy required to free an electron from the bulk material. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_affinity for example. It takes some 4eV to get an electron out of silicon, and 1.1eV to take it from the valance to the conduction band.

Comment: So can we say that vaccum energy is equal to barrier height and all bands (conduction/valence) lie below this barrier height?